# Why is my code causing problem while running the "while loop" in C++? in the if else satement it keeps printing the wrong output constantly

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;



int main()           //geting input part
{
 string wantedWord, name1, name2;
 cout<<"Player one, please enter your name: ";
 cin >> name1;
 cout<<"Player two, please enter your name: ";
 cin >> name2;
 cout << "OK " << name1 << " and "<< name2<<". Let's start the game!/n";
 cout << name1 << ", please input the word you want " << name2 << "to guess: ";
 cin >> wantedWord;

 // find the leght of the word
 int len = wantedWord.size();


 // check whether the string is alphabetical or not
 char w;    // w = the charater on that specific index 
 int n = 0;   // n = index 
 while ( n < len && n >= 0)
 {
    w = wantedWord[n];
    if ((int(w) >= 65 && int(w) <= 90) || ( int(w) >= 97 && int(w) <= 122))
    {
        n += 1;
        cout << w << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Invalid word! Try again." << endl;    //this gives me an infinite loop why?
        cout << name1 << ", please input the word you want " << name2 << "to guess: ";
        cin >> wantedWord;
    }
    
 }
```

}

My problem is accuring at the "// check whether the string is alphabetical or not" part. When I enter "CS201" as an invalid input, it works fine at first and asks me to enter another word. But then I enter a valid word such as "banana" but again it says "Invalid word! Try again." when it's supposed to accept the input as valid. Why am I getting this error? I'm very new to C++ so if it's not a good question sorry for that.

Comment: After changing `wantedWord` the length is no longer correct. Furthermore you'll want to check the new word from the start. I recommend writing a function for the check btw; this will help you seperate the input logic from the correctness check: `bool CheckInput(const std::string& value) { ... }`; Also I strongly recommend not hardcoding character codes, but using char literals instead, since this makes the code much more readable: `if ((w >= 'a' && w <= 'z') || (w >= 'A' && w <= 'Z'))`. Btw: why do you use `int` instead of `size_t` as index/size and why do you check for negative `n`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to make a new function for the check. I used int beause thats pretty much all I've learned in school yet. Also I wasnt trying to check for negative n. I was just strying to make sure that len>n>=0.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few corrections to your code.

- Added return 0 in the end with a brace.
- Replaced /n by \n .(Irrelevant in this context but important.)
- Resetting the value of n to zero as soon as a new input is taken inside the else statement.
  Since you didn't reset the value of n to zero you were getting error if first attempt was invalid input(as you said in the code).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() //geting input part
{
    string wantedWord, name1, name2;
    cout << "Player one, please enter your name: ";
    cin >> name1;
    cout << "Player two, please enter your name: ";
    cin >> name2;
    cout << "OK " << name1 << " and " << name2 << ". Let's start the game!\n";
    cout << name1 << ", please input the word you want " << name2 << "to guess: ";
    cin >> wantedWord;

    // find the leght of the word
    int len = wantedWord.size();

    // check whether the string is alphabetical or not
    char w;    // w = the charater on that specific index
    int n = 0; // n = index
    while (n < len && n >= 0)
    {
        w = wantedWord[n];
        if ((int(w) >= 65 && int(w) <= 90) || (int(w) >= 97 && int(w) <= 122))
        {
            n ++;
            cout << w << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid word! Try again." << endl; //this gives me an infinite loop why?
            cout << name1 << ", please input the word you want " << name2 << "to guess: ";
            cin >> wantedWord;
            n=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it was helpful. If you are unable to understand please let me know in comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of the corrections. However, it is still giving me the same error :( idk why, n=0 actually makes sense.

Comment: int len1 = wantedWord.size();           
len = len1;                                         
n=0;              I added this at the end of my code, its working now, thank you!

Comment: @elf wantedWord[0] means the first chracter of the string wantedWord,  wantedWord[1] means the second chracter of the string wantedWord and so on.

Comment: @elf Yeah I should have updated the value of len while getting a new string. You did this declaring a new variable len1 which is also correct.